# Before delete trigger using transact-SQL

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-delete

I need to prevent from deleting an user who's occupation is 'Programmer'.
So, the database table structure is:

```
 TABLE Client
 Id   |   Name    |    SSN    |    Occupation    |    Birthdate    |
```

The trigger I have created so far looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_User_Occupation
ON dbo.Client
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT c.Occupation
    FROM deleted AS d
    INNER JOIN Client as c ON d.Id = c.Id) = 'Programmer'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'YES';
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISEERROR(SELECT 'Could not delete client because he is a programmer');
END
END
GO
```

I guess that the row is deleted before it can be compared, but I don't know the right way to approach this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use Instead Of Delete trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct syntax is here:

(You do not need join deleted table to table itself, in deleted is whole row from delete statement...) But be aware a fact, that you are not able to do batch delete in this case. It will work only for row deletes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_User_Occupation
ON dbo.Client
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT Occupation FROM deleted) = 'Programmer'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'YES';

        ROLLBACK

        RAISERROR ('Could not delete client because he is a programmer', -- Message text  
                    16, -- Severity 
                    1 -- State
                    )

    END
END
GO
```

For batch commands is better to use there following statement:

```
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted WHERE Occupation = 'Programmer') > 0
```

But ofc if you want to join on this table, you need to use

```
INSTEAD OF DELETE
```

And in this case you dont need use `ROLLBACK`

Finnaly it should looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_User_Occupation
ON dbo.Client
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT Occupation FROM deleted) = 'Programmer'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'YES';        

        RAISERROR ('Could not delete client because he is a programmer', -- Message text  
                    16, -- Severity 
                    1 -- State
                    )

    END
END
GO
```